# Encontrar el valor minimo dentro de un for loop

Tags: javascript

Estoy haciendo un script que admita 10 numeros y me indique cuales son numeros pares e imprares, el numero menor y mayor.
El problema que tengo es que me muestra 10 como numero menor, este es mi codigo por si pudieran darme feedback.
Lo que busco es que me muestre el numero menor de los que el usuario ingresa pero me muestra 0

````
for(n = 0; n <= 10; n++) { 
    n = parseInt(prompt("Digite un numero:"));
    if (n % 2 == 0) {
        par++
    } else {
        impar++
    }
    mayor = Math.max(n, mayor);
    menor = Math.min(n, menor);
}   

document.write("De los numeros 10 numeros ingresados " + par + " son pares!");
document.write("<br> De los numeros 10 numeros ingresados " + impar + " son impares!");
document.write("<br> De los numeros 10 numeros ingresados " + mayor + " es el numero mayor");
document.write("<br> De los 10 numeros ingresados " + menor + " es el numero menor");```
````

Comment: Estas usando la variable `n` como contador y como numero a comparar, lo cual es un error.  Cambia el nombre de la variable.

Answer (score 1):

ya me funciona!!! Les dejo el codigo por aca, lo que hice fue hacer un array con los inputs y sobre ese array sacar el max y min

````
var num = [], par = 0, impar = 0, mayor = 0, menor = 0;
for(n = 0; n <= 9; n++) { 
    num[n] = parseInt(prompt("Digite un numero:"));
    if (n % 2 == 0) {
        par++
    } else {
        impar++
    }
    mayor = Math.max.apply(null, num);
    menor = Math.min.apply(null, num);
}   

document.write("De los numeros 10 numeros ingresados " + par + " son pares!");
document.write("<br> De los numeros 10 numeros ingresados " + impar + " son impares!");
document.write("<br> De los numeros 10 numeros ingresados " + mayor + " es el numero mayor");
document.write("<br> De los 10 numeros ingresados " + menor + " es el numero menor");```
````

Answer (score 0):

```html
<script>
    let par = 0;
    let impar = 0;

    let mayor = null;
    let menor = null;

    let total = 10;
    const numbers = [];
    while(total > 0) {
        numbers.push(parseInt(prompt("Digite un numero:")));

        total--;
    }

    total = numbers.length;
    for (let index = 0; index < total; index++) {
        const n = numbers[index];
        menor = (menor === null) ? n : menor;
        mayor = (mayor === null) ? n : mayor;


        if (n % 2 == 0) {
            par++
        } else {
            impar++
        }

        if (index + 1 < total) {
            const nextNumber = numbers[index + 1];
            const tempMenor = (n < nextNumber) ? n : nextNumber;
            const tempMayor = (n > nextNumber) ? n : nextNumber;

            menor = (menor < tempMenor) ? menor : tempMenor;
            mayor = (mayor > tempMayor) ? mayor : tempMayor;
        }
    }

    document.write("De los numeros 10 numeros ingresados " + par + " son pares!");
    document.write("<br> De los numeros 10 numeros ingresados " + impar + " son impares!");
    document.write("<br> De los numeros 10 numeros ingresados " + mayor + " es el numero mayor");
    document.write("<br> De los 10 numeros ingresados " + menor + " es el numero menor");
</script>
```

Lo habitual para obtener el mayor y el menor numero de una serie, es primero tener esa serie, ya que puedes recorrerlos e ir comparando, de la otra forma la opción sería usar un almacenamiento, por ejemplo un array para el mayor y otro para el menor, si esta vació (primer número) se guarda el número en ambos. Con cada nuevo número se compara con el ya almacenado y se reemplaza en su caso, y el ejemplo:

```html
<script>
    let par = 0;
    let impar = 0;

    const mayor = [];
    const menor = [];

    let total = 10;
    for (let index = 0; index < total; index++) {
        const n = parseInt(prompt("Digite un numero:"));
        if (mayor.length === 0 || mayor[0] < n) {
            mayor[0] = n;
        }
        if (menor.length === 0 || menor[0] > n) {
            menor[0] = n;
        }


        if (n % 2 == 0) {
            par++
        } else {
            impar++
        }
    }

    document.write("De los numeros 10 numeros ingresados " + par + " son pares!");
    document.write("<br> De los numeros 10 numeros ingresados " + impar + " son impares!");
    document.write("<br> De los numeros 10 numeros ingresados " + mayor + " es el numero mayor");
    document.write("<br> De los 10 numeros ingresados " + menor + " es el numero menor");
</script>
```